# Code in comment overflows

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

Due to the code in the comment to question [Laravel install Agent with composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344380/laravel-install-agent-with-composer#comment33960915_22344380), the contents overflows the comment box. Removing `white-space: pre-wrap` fixes the problem.

[image: screenshot of problem].

This was found in Firefox 31.0 on Arch Linux, and persists with Firefox 32.

Comment: How did they even do that? `[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known.`

Comment: Lots and lots of space characters, apparently. Removing them fixes the formatting for me on Firefox. Definitely looks like a bug, yup, although it might be a client-side one.

Comment: Confirmed that spaces are causing an overflow in Firefox 31. Could not reproduce on Chromium 36 by the way.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Don't worry, IE11 overflowed as well.

Comment: @Kendra, that's because IE11 wants to be Firefox with all its heart. They should have thought that would backfire in some way.

Comment: *"Removing white-space: pre-wrap fixes the problem"* - allowing users with enough rep to migrate the information back into the question would fix it too. Instead, folks have to get a moderator involved.

Comment: *[Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208)*

Comment: I got the same result with Firefox 31.0 on Windows.

Comment: Found similar comments, but without any code formatting, as far as I can see, at least in Firefox 31.0. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7162814/806975

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez Confirmed with Firefox 32.0.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for bringing this up. I've modified the CSS for `.comment-text code` blocks to set `white-space: normal` which is honored due to CSS specificity. As a result, code blocks in comments should not overflow any longer. Note that this only affects code blocks in comments, not in questions or answers. This will be live after the next prod release (meta: > `rev 2014.9.25.2605`, q&a: > `rev 2014.9.25.1892`).

Comment: Great, I'll wait for the next build. How often does SE roll out?

Comment: 1-10x a day or so. It'll surely be within the next 24 hours.

Comment: This causes multiple spaces to be collapsed into a single one, for example `/  /` appears to only contain one space. This caused some confusion in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586141/replace-using-gsub-in-awk#comment53026335_32586227)!

Comment: This seems to be causing more troubles: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339485/formatting-of-code-in-comments-does-not-preserve-spaces

Comment: This fix was wrong. Instead of overriding `.comment-text code` and setting `white-space` back to normal, you should have left `pre-wrap` in place, and use [`word-wrap/overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) to allow breaking in the middle of something.

Comment: Happening again: [Comment code format overflow covered by job](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403230/comment-code-format-overflow-covered-by-job)