# Comments Overlapping with Related Questions

Tags: bug, comments, design

I was browsing a [duplicated-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) when I came across this interesting layout glitch:

[image]

Basically, all the comments on the page are scrolling too far to the right and are overlapping with the "Related Questions" section of this particular question. I can't seem to duplicate this issue on other pages, and I've tried reloading, force-reloading (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>), clearing my browser, etc. Am I the only one experiencing this issue?

Also, tested in Internet Explorer, Firefox Developer Edition, Firefox standard and Chrome; issue present in both versions of Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: My guess is that UTF shenanigans with [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php#comment37396677_16389034) kill the word-wrapping-algo and force the comment-container to expand uncontrolled to the right.

Comment: This was [reported last August](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269890/code-in-comment-overflows) and supposedly fixed- Apparently this bug has reared its ugly head yet again.

Comment: @Kendra: No, that's a different problem with similar symptoms.

Comment: @Deduplicator You're right, looking at it a little closer- Then I guess instead of "rearing its ugly head yet again" this bug has simply found a new way to manifest itself.

Comment: Can you please link the right question which produce that produce.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Scroll down to the first answer. If you're on Chrome, you still won't see the issue. (I assume it's only happening on the answer, as that's what the OP shows. I can't actually see it myself, since I'm running Chrome.) EDIT: Yes, after checking in IE, only the comments on the first answer actually have this issue.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think you're correct on what's causing the issue- Using IE's dev tools to hide that comment fixes all the other comments.

Comment: oh I can see it.I use firefox.