# Formatting of code in comments does not preserve spaces

Tags: bug, comments, design, code-formatting

I entered a comment of the form `` Omit the `& ` entirely `` containing a segment in backticks. However, the space after the `&` inside the code segment was collapsed with the following space outside the code segment.

[image]

This is due to a CSS rule for `.comment-text code`, which overrides the setting for `white-space`:

[image]

Instead of overriding `.comment-text code` and setting `white-space` back to `normal`, the correct approach is to leave `pre-wrap` in place, and use `word-wrap/overflow-wrap` to allow breaking in the middle of something, since failing to wrap was the problem they were apparently trying to solve.

Also, I notice that hyphens (`-`) within code runs in comments are treated as a hyphenation opportunity, which seems wrong.

Comment: Live example: Omit the `& ` entirely

Comment: Just a quick test: `code block with
a linebreak`. <-- The only reason I can think of for the `white-space: normal;`, but the linebreak is removed in the rendered output, any way.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think that is the reason, actually: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272194/390808