# Code block overflows on Google Chrome

Tags: bug, design, code-formatting

In rare circumstances a code block overflows the container in Google Chrome. It works fine in Firefox.

Example: [php 5.3/mysql: why doesn't apache see mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450130/php-5-3-mysql-why-doesnt-apache-see-mysql)

[image: Google Chrome]

Comment: That's not a code block though, that's formatted as inline code (single backticks) which is not appropriate and causes this behavior. If this were a code block, you'd get scroll bars and the issue would be gone (however, it'd be even better to remove the trailing space). Still, this should probably be fixed.

Comment: Related: [Code in comment overflows](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269890/215552)