# Markdown sections overlap on the suggested edits page

Tags: bug, design, suggested-edits

While going through the suggested edits today, I noticed this overlap in the markdown sections here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27178546

I was using Google Chrome v84 on Windows with inner window size: 1536 x 754

[image]

Comment: you might want to add your browser/OS etc.. No repro on firefox on WIndows.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox, Safari, or Chrome on macOS.

Comment: Size of the browser window can also make a difference.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome v85 on Windows.

Comment: @10Rep Doesn’t appear to; the review pages seem to be non-responsive.

Comment: @user4642212 for instance i am on ipad and no repro.

Comment: @10 That doesn't necessarily mean that it's because of the size.

Comment: zoom to 100% doesn't resolve the issue on Chrome / Win10

Comment: @10Rep That's likely just a difference in how it handles the CSS. Changing the window size within a given OS/browser doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: Related: [Code in comment overflows](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269890/4642212) and all its linked questions.

Comment: Also [reproducible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdHtj.png) on Opera Windows10

Comment: @10Rep `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`M` on Firefox (desktop) brings up the mobile / responsiveness tester. Resizing the view makes no difference. `div.suggested-edit` has a fixed width of `960px`.

Comment: @user4642212 I see it on windows with chrome.

Comment: Repro in Win10 Chrome 85, *No* repro in Edge or Firefox.