# Comment code format overflow covered by job

Tags: bug, comments, formatting

I just found a overflowing comment. It is covered by a job box (Whatever it's called). If there was some code there, it could not be shown.

[image: Error]

Can we change it to comment covering the job description? (By changing the z-index or something, I guess.)

Or from [the comment by Andrew T.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403230/comment-code-format-overflow-covered-by-job#comment811106_403230) -

> [Another example demonstrating the bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/349029#comment1186575_349029) (warning: big MSE formatting sandbox). The real solution is to prevent comments from overflowing (even for NBSP), not using a z-index or other workarounds.

We can make the comment not overflow.

It seems like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269890/code-in-comment-overflows?noredirect=1&lq=1) is not quite fixed.

Comment: Appears to be a regression of [this bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269890/code-in-comment-overflows) from 2014

Comment: [Another example demonstrating the bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/349029#comment1186575_349029) (warning: big MSE formatting sandbox). The real solution is to prevent comments from overflowing (even for NBSP), not using a z-index or other workarounds.

Comment: @AndrewT. Good idea. I'll post that in the question

Comment: Also, related since 2012: [Why are comments overlapping the sidebar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154788/241919)

Comment: I've noticed that on Ipad, this doesn't happen when on vertical.

Comment: [Another example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036038/is-there-unicode-glyph-symbol-to-represent-search#comment49638509_18367765)

Comment: Cross-site dupe on MSE: [Comment Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361250/289905).