# Comment to this answer is overflowing, design issue or something else?

Tags: bug, design, comments

Comment to this answer is overflowing, design issue or something else?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22648862/5208077

Comment: Duplicate of [Comment code format overflow covered by job](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403230/4642212).